i trying to add app badge on my flutter project on android mobile
i try many lib on iOS its working even if they say the lib support a android
but its not working on testing on Samsung device
no im trying to make it with kotline and communicate with my flutter project
first i try a small fun return a message from kotlin and its working i do it for being sure that the coummincate is working
know i trying to make badge i try many way Intent and using shortcut.badge lib nut its not working
this is my kotlin code i dont have any error by the way but tits not working
package com.beeorder.customer

import android.app.NotificationChannel
import android.app.NotificationManager
import android.app.PendingIntent
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel
import me.leolin.shortcutbadger.ShortcutBadger


class MainActivity : FlutterActivity() {
    private val CHANNEL = "com.beeorder.customer/kotlin"

    override fun configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
        MethodChannel(
            flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger,
            CHANNEL
        ).setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->
            if (call.method == "getSimpleMessage") {
                val message = "Hello from Native Android!"
                result.success(message) // Send the message back to Flutter
            } else if (call.method == "updateBadgeCount") {
                ShortcutBadger.applyCount(applicationContext, 5)
                val context = applicationContext
                val badgeIntent = Intent("android.intent.action.BADGE_COUNT_UPDATE")
                badgeIntent.putExtra("badge_count", 5)
                badgeIntent.putExtra(
                    "badge_count_package_name",
                    context.packageName
                )
                badgeIntent.putExtra("badge_count_class_name", MainActivity::class.java.name)
                context.sendBroadcast(badgeIntent)
                result.success("badge is done ")


            } else {
                result.notImplemented()
            }
        }
    }

}


this is my badgeManager File on flutter
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class FlutterAppBadger {
  static const MethodChannel _channel = MethodChannel("com.beeorder.customer/kotlin");



  static Future<void> updateBadgeCount(int count) async {
    try {
      await _channel.invokeMethod('updateBadgeCount');
    } catch (e){
      return;
    }
  }

  static Future<void> removeBadge() async {
    await _channel.invokeMethod('removeBadge');
  }

  static Future<bool> isAppBadgeSupported() async {
    try {
      var   message = await _channel.invokeMethod('getSimpleMessage');
       return true;
    } catch (e) {
      return false;
    }
  }
}

i expected to make  A appBadge
